# How to test image preview with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have js code that displays an image preview after adding a picture.

```
 function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#attach").change(function () {
      readURL(this);
  });
});
```

And html:

```
<img id="preview" style="width:400px;height:400px;">

<label for="attach">
  <span>Click to add picture</span>
</label>

<input class="hidden" id="attach" type="file" name="profile[image]">
```

Check out [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/Vjprje) example.

Question: Using capybara how can I test that image preview shows up when I attach a picture?
I know we can check **img** tag for a **src** but how can I combine Capybara with Javascript code?

Simply using **attach_file()** doesn't do anything useful here since Capybara isn't friendly with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean about Capybara not being friendly with JS, however there is an inconsistency in your example since your file input has an id of "attach" and your JS change listener is listening on '#inputFile' -  assuming that is fixed (in this code I assumed the input id was supposed to be 'attach') then you can do

```
execute_script('$("#attach").removeClass("hidden")') #make input visible so you can attach to it
attach_file('attach', 'some_file.jpg') #attach the file
expect(page).to have_css('#preview[src]') #confirm a src attribute was set
```

Comment: I can't test your solution right now, but I'm just curious. Do you believe that Capybara can trigger tag changes set by JS code?

Comment: @BillyLogan Capybara doesn't trigger anything - PhantomJS is the "browser" used by poltergeist and will trigger a change event when attach_file is used.

Comment: Do you have any idea how one can check if file was attached?

Comment: @BillyLogan submit the form and make sure the model is created -- it sounds like you're getting way too fine-grained in your feature tests.